# How can I filter/find on an ElementCriteriaModel?

Tags: elementcriteriamodel

I have already retrieved a set of all Entries from a channel and need to now find one in the template without hitting the DB again (this find is in a loop so I don't want to grab a single result from the DB for every iteration through the loop):

```
{% set entries = craft.entries.section('mySection').get %}
```

How can I then pluck out a specific entry by field match? I've tried this:

```
{% set entry = entries.find('myFieldHandle', mySearchVariable) %}
```

This doesn't seem to work for me though in that I don't get a match.

Comment: Would it work to just search for the entries you are looking for in the first place instead of grabbing all the entries in the section?

Comment: I'm already doing that, however I was looking to avoid the loop in the template

Comment: *"this find is in a loop"* – what do you mean with that?

Comment: Sorry ignore that part - there is no db overhead, I'm just looking to avoid looping in the template

Answer (score 2):

**Update**
I may have found a better option for you. Looks like you were on the right track after all, but with some quotes misplaced.

```
{% set entries = craft.entries.section('mySection') %}
{% set entry = entries.find({myFieldHandle:'mySearchVariable'})[0] %}
{{ entry.title }}
```

Although looks like this hits the database again (thanks carlcs).

Maybe back to the orginal answer then, which was:

```
{% set entries = craft.entries.section('mySection') %}
{% for entry in entries if entry.myFieldHandle == 'myVariable' %}
    {{ entry.title }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I have a loop at present, which works. I was hoping there might be some kind of shortcut method that would filter the model by field value. Thanks though.

Comment: After playing around some more I was able to get the 'find' working properly. I have updated the answer. See if that helps.

Comment: This adds another database query for each `find()`?

Comment: @carlcs hmm... ya... on second look I think you may be right.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience the `search` function is a little more forgiving to work with than `find`.

See [Searching](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/searching) in the Craft documentation for the syntax and available search attributes.

```
{% set entries = craft.entries.section('mySection') %}
{% set searchResults = entries.search('myFieldHandle:mySearchVariable') %}

{% if searchResults %}
  {% for entry in searchResults %}
    {{ entry.title }}
  {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

If you want to avoid the for loop and you're feeling lucky about the search result, you can always limit your search with `first()`.

```
{% set entry = entries.search('myFieldHandle:mySearchVariable').first() %}

{% if entry %}
  {{ entry.title }}
{% endif %}
```

This does add extra queries for each search you run, tho.

If your goal is to avoid db queries, use a for loop to match against your search criteria. Optionally, you can use the [MN Break and Continue](https://github.com/marionnewlevant/craft-mnbreakandcontinue) plugin to stop looping after the first match is made.

```
{% for entry in entries if entry.myFieldHandle == 'myVariable' %}
  {{ entry.title }}
  {% break %}
{% endfor %}
```